# Что за параметры _client_enable_auto_unregister и _undo_autotune?

Tags: sql, oracle, dba

В настройках бд увидел строчки:

```
_client_enable_auto_unregister = TRUE
_undo_autotune = FALSE
```

Понятно, что знак подчеркивания перед параметром говорит о том, что эти параметры не документированы и не рекомендуются к использованию самостоятельно. Но что они делают?
Про `_undo_autotune` нашел, что он отвечает за `enable auto tuning of undo_retention`, но не понял, что под этим подразумевается.

Comment: у вас есть доступ к [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com)?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению. Лицензии закуплены, но простым разработчикам Support ID не дают =\

Comment: [здесь есть кое-что](https://www.net-isle.com/database/e000-process-consuming-cpu-constantly/)

Comment: Нашел даже целый список этих параметров, но не понимаю, что же именно он делает. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_12c_hidden_undocumented_parameters.htm

Comment: что такое, сбой отправки с таймаутом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрытый параметр `_client_enable_auto_unregister` используется для "лечения" Bug 9735536 в Oracle 11.2.0.4 и старше (см. SOLUTION ниже).

**Описание "бага":**

Event Monitor (EMON) slave process is consuming CPU.
Multiple stacks from the process obtained via

```
connect / as sysdba

oradebug setospid 1379
```

or use  the following to find EMON process

```
In 11g ps -ef | grep EMON

In 12c ps-ef |grep ennn

oradebug SHORT_STACK
```

have the form

```
Oracle pid: 43, Unix process pid: 1379, image: oracle@feltux3154 (E000)
```

> _write()+10<-nttwr()+275<-nsntwrn()+111<-nspsend()+935<-nsdo()+4694<-nsfull_sd()+46<-kpcesend()+952<-kponsnd()+392<-kponepms()+1729<-kponprmsg()+405<-kponemn0()+597<-kponemn()+1152<-ksvrdp()+3653<-opirip()+901<-opidrv()+684<-sou2o()+87<-opimai_real()+280<-ssthrdmain()+295<-main()+203<-_start()+108

which indicates it is stuck in a network write.

**CAUSE:**

> The cause of this issue has been identified in unpublished enhancement
>   Bug 9735536.  The emon process is stuck in a network write probably
>   trying to communicate with a client that is not responding and this
>   fix detects this and removes the unreachable client.

**SOLUTION:**

The workaround is to kill the emon slave process via

kill -9 ps_id

where ps_id is the process id of the emon slave.

The emon slave will automatically restart when it is next required to do so.

To permanently resolve the issue if the release is pre-11.2.0.3 apply Patch 9735536 (Just apply the fix, no need to set any underscore parameters to activate)

**In 11.2.0.4 onwards** do the following to enable the fix for unpublished Bug 9735536 :

```
connect / as sysdba

alter system set "_client_enable_auto_unregister"=true scope=spfile

shutdown immediate

startup
```